# Release "ownership" of COM object in .NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, com

I have a customer/partner who's trying to link their application with ours using our exposed COM functionality.  So far, they've got a COM object which represents an instance of our software package and then use our COM methods to programmatically build something up for the user based on what they've done in their application.  It's essentially an "export" feature.

What they've asked me to do, which I can't work out how to do is to allow the user to decide when the instance is closed.  What I mean by this is when our software package is loaded up, it's viewable and is interacted with by the user.  When they are finished they'd naturally click the cross at the top right to exit the software.  This doesn't work as the COM object is still "active" in their application. Our software package can only be closed by killing the process in task manager whilst the application that loaded it via COM remains open. Once their application exits, ours will automatically close. It seems as if their application "owns" ours because of the COM call.

I've made a quick demo app in C# to try using things like `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(myObject)` to no avail.

I realise that using COM for this kind of thing isn't really what it is intended for, but hopefully there's some sort of workaround?  The customer/partner is using VB.NET but C# is fine.

Comment: Please clarify if your application is automated from inside application itself (similar to VBA scripting inside VS or Office applications) or from outside (similar to using Word automation to create new document from you own console app/script)?

Comment: They can't close a window?  That makes no sense, you'll need to clarify.

Comment: It's from outside, they're using VB to start a new process by referencing our exe and instantiating a COM object from it. We have an "Open" which does exactly what it sounds like, opens a usable window of our software package. In terms of not being able to close the window, you can't click the red X at the top right, well you can but nothing happens. It will only close when their VB application is closed. I don't know a lot about COM interop but it seems like the VB app has ownership or is the parent of that process.

Comment: It sounds like their application is the issue.  They should be disposing of your object as soon as they are done with it. It is possible that your application should notify them as it is closed by handling the `Form.Closing Event` and setting some status.

Comment: Can you explain more precisely the interaction between applications? When I create something used as COM in .net (register for COM interop) it is a .dll (and a .tlb I use from VB6). It runs in process which called it. However you mention stopping in taskmanager. Does the application starting a new process? Is not there missing some process.close?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've left out some critical information about your own application, including most importantly how you are implementing the COM interfaces that you expose to the client application. One aspect of your description that is a red flag for me is the instantiation of your application. You say that the client application is, "using VB to start a new process by referencing our exe." This shouldn't be necessary if you've properly implemented and registered your COM server. Let me tell you the architecture I would use to accomplish what you ask, and hopefully this will be useful to you.

To begin with, if you want to provide a COM object from within a separate process, the proper way is to implement a COM out of process server. With an out of process server, COM will start your application automatically when a client requests one of your interfaces through COM. Part of the implementation requirements of an out of process server is to shut down automatically when the last COM client releases their last interface pointer.

In order to expose a user interface from the out of process server, you'll want to spawn a separate Single-threaded Apartment (STA) thread with a message loop. This will allow you to close any window on the STA thread, including the main window, without killing your COM server. That's because the COM server implementation will be running it's own Multi-threaded Apartment (MTA) message loop thread to support the COM out of proc calls. The MTA thread is the main application thread, and the server will shut down it down when the last client interface is released.

A COM server *should not* shut down while interfaces remain unreleased. This means the client application has a responsibility to release interfaces properly. But your .NET test frame should have done this, so it appears something is not right with your implementation.

Assuming you follow this guidance, you will need a plan for handling the scenario in which the last client interface is release but you still have open UI windows. Once you get everything set up correctly, this shouldn't be a major problem. For example, you can simply take a reference to one of your own interfaces while the UI is open, this would prevent an MTA shutdown.